# UnsatisfiedLinkError when calling native method packaged in jar file

Tags: java-native-interface

I am getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.fundamenture.solvocommons.utility.parsers.tklib.test()V when calling native C method test() when calling the class packaged in a jar file. Same code runs fine when calling the java file directly

Note that loading the library with code

```
System.loadLibrary("tklib");
```

runs fine, it is only at the point of calling the method test() that the exception occurs. This means that the java code can load the library properly, only calling the method is failing

The code runs fine when called via command line in a main method as follows

```
java -cp . -Djava.library.path=. tklib
```

Below is my java code with the main method running fine from command line

```
class tklib {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("tklib"); // loading libtklib.so
    }

    private native void test();

    private native boolean initialize(String configuration);

    private native void shutdown();

    private native String unpack(String keyname, String secureddata);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new tklib().test();

        new tklib().shutdown();
    }
}
```

When I package the project as a jar file and calling the method I am getting the UnsatisfiedLinkError at the point when new tklib().test() is called.

Comment: Are you sure that you load the exact same `libtklib.so` when you're running in JBoss? Maybe you have one lying around that was built for a previous different version of the Java code and JBoss finds that